# Call function after some period time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having a problem and don't know how to solve it. I have two functions in Javascript, both are called via AJAX, first function get values and insert records in DB and second function reads from DB and show the results. Since first function get values remotely sometimes response times are larger than second function and for that reason second function executes before first. What I need is to call `buildTablesFromDB()` only if AJAX call for `buildClassification()` is done. This is how my code looks like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function buildTablesFromDB() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://local/parser/reader.php",
            success: function(data) {
                $("#clasification-data").html();

                if (data.response === false) {
                    $(".alert").show();
                    $(".close").after(data.error);
                } else {
                    if (data.html_content.position.length != 0) {
                        $("#clasification-holder").show();
                        var iterator = data.html_content.position;
                        var tr = "";
                        $.each(iterator, function(key, value) {
                            tr += "<tr>";
                            tr += '<td><img src="' + value.team_image + '" alt="' + value.team_name + '" title="' + value.team_name + '">&nbsp;&nbsp;' + value.team_name + '</td>';
                            tr += '<td>' + value.team_jj + '</td>';
                            tr += '<td>' + value.team_jg + '</td>';
                            tr += '<td>' + value.team_jp + '</td>';
                            tr += '<td>' + value.team_difference + '</td>';
                            tr += '<td><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-play"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-stop"></span></td>';
                            tr += '</tr>';
                        });

                        $("#clasification-data").html(tr);
                    }
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                request.abort();
            }
        });
    }

    function buildClassification() {
        var request = $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            url: "http://local/parser/parser.php",
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.response === false) {
                    // some error
                }
            },
            error: function() {
                request.abort();
            }
        });
    }

    window.setInterval(function() {
        buildClassification();
    }, 1800000); // Updates table results each 30 minutes

    window.setInterval(function() {
        buildTablesFromDB();
    }, 1800000); // Updates table results each 30 minutes

    buildClassification();
    buildTablesFromDB();
});
```

How I can get this done?

Comment: Firstly move the functions outside the jquery document.ready

Comment: Also, you should move the markup out of the javascript code. Try using something like handlebars (http://handlebarsjs.com/) to create the html for the table row.

Comment: @pax162 thanks I'll take into account but right now I feel good with this, maybe for large development `handlebarsjs` is the right solution

Comment: @mplungjan is that right? Ohhh I tough that all the JS code should go inside `$(document).ready()` definition, I learn something new today

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can call `buildTablesFromDB()` in the callback method of `buildClassification()`
e.g.

```
....
dataType: 'json',
        url: "http://local/parser/parser.php",
        success: function(data) {
            if (data.response === false) {
                //

            }else{
                buildTablesFromDB();
            }
        },
```